# Excluding bat file from bat execution

Tags: batch-file

I have bat file that puts every file in a folder according to the name of the file.  However when I run the bat file it will put the bat file in a folder as well.  I want to exclude bat file extensions from doing so because I have to go into each folder and cut the bat file to bring it back to the parent folder.  This is my current bat file:

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.*) do (

md "%%~na" 2>nul

move "%%a" "%%~na"

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested:

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.*) do (

 if "%~nx0" neq "%%~nxa" (
   md "%%~na" 2>nul
   move "%%a" "%%~na"
 )

)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works perfectly thank you so much npocmaka